# Vim script: check if the current word is/isn't a C/C++ keyword

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm working on a small vim plugin which should highlight current word occurrences after cursor idle.
I have a highlight part, and what I need is to check if the current word is not a C/C++ keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that depending on current syntax highlight script. Say, this function returns if your cursor is on some access modifier (`public`, `protected`, etc), or some C++ type (say, `bool`, etc) :

```
function! IsCppAccessOrType()
   return match(synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name"), '\v\CcppAccess|cppType') >= 0
endfunction
```

But, again, this will completely depend on current syntax script. Example above depends on standard `syntax/cpp.vim` provided with Vim 7.3 .

---

By the way, there is very useful trick to deal with syntax highlight stuff:

```
" Show syntax highlighting groups for word under cursor 
nnoremap <silent> <F10> :call <SID>SynStack()<CR>
function! <SID>SynStack()
   if !exists("*synstack")
      return
   endif
   echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
endfunc
```

Add this to your `vimrc`, and when you press <kbd>F10</kbd>, stack of syntax items will be echoed ( see `:help synstack` for more details ).

I have found this trick somewhere on http://vimbits.com .

Comment: Thank you very much :)
It seems that synID returns non-zero for all recognizable keywords, and all I need is to check:
`synID(line("."), col("."), 1) != 0`
no need for -1 for column.

Comment: Glad to help :) And yep, you're right, `-1` for column came from autocomplete script, it is needed there to handle a dot. I already removed it from the answer, thanks for that notice.

Comment: What does it mean when the SynStack function returns empty brackets, `[]`? I'm getting that for variables in Python.